# How can I use two Firefox profiles?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-profile

I am using Windows 10 and want to use one installation of Firefox with two different profiles for the same logged in Windows user.

How can I set this up, so that I may easily launch both profiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to create another Firefox profile as follows:

1. Press <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `firefox.exe -p` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the **Firefox Profile Manager**

   [image: Firefox Profile Manager]
3. Click on the <kbd>Create Profile...</kbd> button.  In the subsequent window, choose a unique name for your alternate Firefox profile.

   [image: Create Profile Wizard]
4. Click the <kbd>Finish</kbd> button

After that, you have a choice of methods to utilize:

- You can reopen the Firefox Profile Manager and uncheck the box that says *Use the selected profile without asking at startup*.  After that, each time you open Firefox you will be queried to choose a profile for that session.
- If you truly want to use multiple Firefox profiles simultaneously, the easiest method would be to create a Firefox shortcut with the arguments `-p -no-remote` as seen below:

  [image: Firefox No Remote]

When you utilize that shortcut, it will not be affected if Firefox is already running a different profile and ask you to select which profile to use while opening another Firefox process.

- Last but not least, you could potentially [create dedicated shortcuts for each Firefox profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Opening_a_new_instance_of_Firefox_with_another_profile) and launch them as desired using the following format:

  `"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -P "ProfileName" -no-remote`

([Source](http://www.howtogeek.com/209320/how-to-set-up-and-use-multiple-profiles-user-accounts-in-firefox/))